# I am trying to open another activity from a button click in flutter but it is showing some error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page 1"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Next Page"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => nextPage()),
                  );
                },
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class nextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page 2"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Go Back!"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code i am using to navigate to a new page but i am facing a problem even though compiler is not throwing any error

This is the error message i am getting

**Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.**

I am getting this error when i am clicking on the button

Answer (score 4):

You need `home : Builder( builder: (context) =>` and Second Page remove MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Page 1"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("Next Page"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => nextPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Page 1"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("Next Page"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => nextPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class nextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 2"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Go Back!"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page 1"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Next Page"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(NextPage.routeName),
                  );
                },
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
static const routeName = '/next-page';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page 2"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Go Back!"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the Navigator (in MyApp class) with the context you got before creating MaterialApp(). Wrap your MaterialButton with a Builder like so:

```
children: <Widget>[
            Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
                 MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("Go Back!"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(innerContext);
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
             }
            );
         ],
```

Besides this, some more issues:

- i would also think about using onWillPop property for all those android use cases.
- never ever use another MaterialApp() while navigating your app, use Scaffold() for example for childs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just move the MaterialApp Widget to the main()

```
main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
    home: MyApp(),
  ),
);
```

and remove it from the other classes.

You only need one MaterialApp widget for your app. It's like "root" widget which configures the top-level Navigator, as you can see in documentation.